# Disable Text Box Selection or Clicking

Tags: c#, textbox

Is there a way to disable a user from clicking within a text box? I've tried .ReadOnly but this disables the user from typing in the text box. I want to be able to let the user type their name maybe "Peter" but disallow clicking back so they can't type over.

Comment: Why can't the user fix a typo?

Comment: @LarsTech It was just an example. The way I want my program to work is disallow any click backs on selection and type over or add over the already typed inputs.

Comment: What about tabbing and typing, or selecting with the arrow keys?  Do you want to disallow those too?  why would you want a user to add _more_ text but not change the text that's already there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the MouseUp event:

```
void textBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If WPF you can bind Focusable and just return false once a value has been set.  Or just explicitly call tbDisable.Focusable = False;

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is listening to the "Preview..." mouse events of the TextBox and setting `e.Handled = true`. In contrast to the accepted answer this will fully prevent mouse interactions - and not just hide the selection on MouseUp.